# make routing be more generic, pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have enabled pagination and routing settings in global.asax like this

```
routes.MapRoute("Users", "Index/{page}",
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" });
```

Now I need to apply these to every controller which sends page parameter. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `?page=1`? This is what google and stackoverflow use. There is no reason to have everything in the route

Comment: ofcourse there is nothing wrong with that approach, but I want to use this, is that a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can approach it.

- Add a `page` parameter to all your Action methods:

```
    public ActionResult SomeAction(int? page)`
    {
       if (page.HasValue) ...
    }
```

- Access the `RouteData` directly using:

```
    RouteData.Values["page"]
```

I guess you might want to consider creating a *Base Controller* that handles repetitive tasks related to paging.

Comment: actually I have exact action inside controller with int? page parameter. Can you explain further how can I access directly using  RouteData.Values["page"]). Thanks

Comment: You already have that parameter on the `Users` controller, action `Index`?  Then page should be set when you navigate to Users/Index/1, shouldn't it?  If you wan to use `RouteData`, it's just like that, `RouteData.Values["page"]` should give you the right value, if it's set.

Comment: @dbaseman, the problem with a BaseController is that it's easy to forget to inherit.  Applying a global action filter is generally preferred